How to compare the performance of a linear regression model with a mixed effect model
I am analyzing data on glucose levels in mice between control and genetically modified (KO) mice. I have performed this experiment quite a few times (>5 independent experiments).
For the analysis, I am performing 3 models:

One where I just compare the glucose levels between groups, without taking into consideration the experience effect (~Group).
Another one where I use the Experiment as a covariate, to take into consideration the Experiment Effect (~ Experiment + Group)
Finally, a mixed effect model, with Group as fixed effect and Experiment as random effect (~Group + (1|Experiment)).

Now, I want to compare the three models, to see if they are similar or not and, best case scenario, I can make an informed decision on which model is best. For that, which metric and/or approach should I use? I am currently looking at AICs but, I am a bit unsure on what to use.
Thanks in advance!

I don't see any problem with using AIC to compare your models. A difference of 2 or more between models is a basic rule of thumb, indicating a meaningful difference in support for one model over another.
When comparing AIC between different types of models (eg linear regression vs mixed effects models), it is very important to check that the likelihood is computed consistently across all models. Inconsistent likelihood computation methods can lead to invalid comparisons of AIC values, potentially misleading model selection. In R, I think lm and lmer models do compute the likelihood in the same way.
Look for the model with the lowest AIC, as it indicates the best balance between goodness of fit and complexity. Ensure that the chosen model aligns with the underlying assumptions of your data and research questions, where appropriate. This will help you select the most appropriate model to draw reliable conclusions from your study.
